# Gradle sync failed: Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync fails every time whenever I open android studio. here is my gradle.build files. Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue? I have gradle 7.2 installed. But I can't figure out what is causing this issue.. I even tried   allowInsecureProtocol = true

**gradle.build/android**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion="16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        
        google()
        mavenCentral(){
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
        maven{
             url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
             
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
         google()
        mavenCentral(){
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
             
            
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
             
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral(){
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
              
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        
        
    }
}
```

**gradle.build/app**

```
buildscript {


    
    repositories {
        google()
    mavenCentral(){
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }

    
   
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        mavenCentral(){
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 28)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '28.0.3')

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 28)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Use either AndroidX library names or old/support library names based on major version of support lib
    def supportLibVersion = safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '27.1.1')
    def supportLibMajorVersion = supportLibVersion.split('\\.')[0] as int
    def appCompatLibName =  (supportLibMajorVersion < 20) ? "androidx.appcompat:appcompat" : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "$appCompatLibName:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${safeExtGet('firebaseMessagingVersion', '21.1.0')}"

}
```

**This is the error I get**

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'RentInCars'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'BintrayJCenter2(http://jcenter.bintray.com/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details. 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'RentInCars'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
    org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'BintrayJCenter2(http://jcenter.bintray.com/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Rent In Cars'

apply from: '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
includeUnimodulesProjects()

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1: Remove `jcenter()`

First of all, the `jcenter()` repository is deprecated now, so try not to use it. Remove all instances of `jcenter()` and the problem should be solved. Add `mavenCentral()` as a replacement.

### Solution 2: Allow Insecure Protocol for `jcenter()`

Everywhere you have mentioned `jcenter()`, expand it like this:

Groovy DSL:

```
jcenter() {
  allowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
jcenter() {
  isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```